# Open XML (Microsoft Word): C# Table Justification

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

How would I align my table in the middle of the word document in open xml?
Here is my code and I want to align the table in the middle.

Here is my code. I'm trying to use TableJustification, but it seems like its not working

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(filepath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordDoc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                mainPart.Document = new Document();
                Body body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(new Body());

                Run run = new Run();
                // Goes through all of the forms
                foreach (var form in forms)
                {

                    Table table = new Table();
                    // Initialize all of the table properties
                    TableProperties tblProp = new TableProperties(
                        new TableBorders(
                            new TopBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.BasicBlackSquares), Size = 16 },
                            new LeftBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.BasicBlackSquares), Size = 16 },
                            new RightBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.BasicBlackSquares), Size = 16 },
                            new BottomBorder() { Val = new EnumValue<BorderValues>(BorderValues.BasicBlackSquares), Size = 16 }
                        )

                    );

                    // Align the table to the center
                    TableJustification justs_center = new TableJustification() { Val = _____  };

                    table.AppendChild(justs_center);
                    table.AppendChild<TableProperties>(tblProp);

                    Paragraph para = body.AppendChild(new Paragraph());
                    Run run_header = para.AppendChild(new Run());
                    RunProperties runProps = run_header.AppendChild(new RunProperties(new Bold()));


                    string username = form.Username;
                    string proces_header = form.HeaderTitle;

                    run_header.AppendChild(new Text(proces_header + " | " + username));

                    for (int i = 0; i < form.FieldList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (!(form.FieldList[i].Token == "USR" || form.FieldList[i].Token == "SNT"))
                        {
                            TableRow tr = new TableRow();

                            TableCell header_cell = new TableCell();

                            header_cell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(form.FieldList[i].Label + ": " + form.FieldList[i].Value))));

                            tr.Append(header_cell);
                            table.Append(tr);
                        }
                    }
                    wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Append(table);

                }

                mainPart.Document.Save();
                wordDoc.Close();
                return "Success";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Table t = new Table(
    new TableProperties(
        ...
        new TableJustification() { Val =  TableRowAlignmentValues.Center},
        ...),
    new TableRow(...),
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying to center the table with the accepted answer did not seem to work. I needed to apply the center justification to all of the rows as well

```
var t = new Table();
var tableProps = new TableProperties();
tableProps.TableJustification = new TableJustification { Val = TableRowAlignmentValues.Center };
t.Append(tableProps);

var row = new TableRow();
var rowProps = new TableRowProperties();
rowProps.Append(new TableJustification { Val = TableRowAlignmentValues.Center });
row.Append(rowProps);
```

Found using the Open XML Productivity Tool

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to apply the center justification to all rows in TableRowProperties only. Even if you don't apply justification in TableProperties, the table will be centered anyway. And I'm interested to find out what is the purpose of justification in TableRowProperties if someone knows.